# How to show a new screen for 10 seconds only: Flutter

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, timer, navigation, periodic-task

I am trying to show a screen in flutter which should appear only for 10 seconds and then should disapper going back to previous screen. How this should be done in the correct manner in flutter. Is it possible to use timer.periodic in Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

In the initstate of the screen that you wish to close add

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10), (){
  //Navigator.pushNamed("routeName");
  Navigator.pop(context);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create new screen with `Future.delayed` inside initState

```dart
class NewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  NewPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewPage> createState() => _NewPageState();
}

class _NewPageState extends State<NewPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10)).then((value) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
    );
  }
}
```